# strcmp segmentation fault in for loop in relation to command line argument

Tags: c, cs50

So I need to enter names into the command line argument. Then it prompts for the number of voters. After that it prompts user to enter their names for votes. If a name that is not mentioned in the command line, it should print "invalid vote". All of it works but after I pass the number of names entered in command line, it gives the error

```
Number of voters: 4
Vote: john
Vote: sally
Vote: sam
**Segmentation fault**
```

Here is the loop

```
 // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name,name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
```

And here is the entire code if necessary

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name,name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Comment: @lurker No, The condition should be `candidate_count > MAX`. `candidate_count == MAX` is allowed becauase the array is allocated as `candidate candidates[MAX];` and the loop condition is `i < candidate_count`.

Comment: @MikeCAT eck, you're right, off by 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop

```
// Loop over all voters
for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
{
    string name = get_string("Vote: ");

    // Check for invalid vote
    if (strcmp(candidates[i].name,name))
    {
        printf("Invalid vote.\n");
    }
}
```

`i` is used as the index for `candidates`.
Actually, this `i` is for counting voters, not candidates.
When there are more voters than candidates, `candidates[i].name` can be `NULL` (because it is not assigned and allocated globally) and passing it to `strcmp()` will lead to Segmentation Fault.

What you want to do should be running another loop to search for who is voted.

```
// Loop over all voters
for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
{
    string name = get_string("Vote: ");

    // Check for invalid vote
    int found = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[j].name,name))
        {
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        printf("Invalid vote.\n");
    }
}
```